# circuitikz voltage arrow is too close to terminals

Tags: tikz-arrows, circuitikz

The code create a voltage drop with an arrow over two open terminals:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[european,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble} % Remove the page numbering

\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\begin{circuitikz}[european, line width=0.8pt]
    \draw (0,0)
    to [short] (1,0)
    to [open, v^>=$v_{A}$, *-*, european voltages] (2,0)
    to [short] (3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem: The arrow is too close to the terminals.
How do I raise the arrow up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `open` component has a width and height, and it was too wide to fit in the given space, confusing the voltage routine.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[european,siunitx]{circuitikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
%\pagenumbering{gobble} % Remove the page numbering

\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/open/width=.4}
\begin{circuitikz}[european, line width=0.8pt]
    \draw (0,0)
    to [short] (1,0)
    to [open, v^>=$v_{A}$, *-*,n=test] (2,0)
    to [short] (3,0);
   \draw[red] (test.ne) -- (test.nw) -- (test.sw) -- (test.se) -- cycle;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I'll just emphasize that the solution is the line: `\ctikzset{bipoles/open/width=.4}`